# Using a Shuffle Function for a Simple Truth or Dare Bot in Discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, shuffle

Like the title says, I'm using JavaScript to build a Discord bot that just handles picking players in a Truth or Dare game. The bot itself functions fine, but it fails to shuffle the players again at the end of a round.

This is my shuffle function

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = ping.length -1, temporaryValue, randomIndex
  
    array[0]=0
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
      array[currentIndex] = currentIndex;
      currentIndex -= 1;
    }

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {  
      
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
       
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
  
    return array;
      console.log(xrandomindex)
  }

  function shuffleassign(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length -1, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = xrandomindex[currentIndex];
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
   array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}
return array;
}
```

And here it is in play

```
else if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}n`))    
        if (count > 1)
            {if (countgame == count -1 ) {
              message.channel.send("The queue is being shuffled.")
              shuffle(xrandomindex)
              shuffleassign(ping)
              shuffleassign(users)
              countgame = 0 } 
          message.channel.send ((ping)[countgame] + " is currently asking " + (ping)[countgame + 1] )
          countgame = countgame +1
          msg = count - countgame 
        }
     else message.channel.send("Too few players to start the game.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle items on the array using this function. You can utilize any value. Have not tested if the players need to have a unique identifier.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // Continue to shuffle while there are items on the index
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick one of the remaining elements
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // Swap it with the current element
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

// Used like so
const arr = ['bob', 'billy', 'tom', 'susan'];
shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: So this would just replace my shuffle function and the call in my code?

Comment: Maybe a link directly to the code would be more useful for helping me: https://github.com/acidminded/server/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Yes, it will replace your shuffle function. Then to assign the players you can do it from left to right. If you have an odd number the person who is left out can be assigned to any of the group randomly.

Comment: The assignment function is overly complicated for what it is doing. After shuffling you don't need to randomize the array anymore. It's already random. Just need to cut it out into pieces. You can even expand the code I have to cut the array into pairs and do one iteration instead of a couple.